# kettle(PDI) 8.1 reading xml error

Tags: xml, dom, kettle, pdi

I encounter a problem using kettle 8.1 for data integrating as follow(but kettle 7.1 works):

```
2018/06/24 14:58:54 - 工单 - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : Unable to open transformation: 
2018/06/24 14:58:54 - 工单 - There was an error passing the exported transformation to the remote server: 
2018/06/24 14:58:54 - 工单 - org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: Error reading information from input streamInvalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.Error reading information from input streamInvalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.   at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:528)  at org.pentaho.di.www.RegisterPackageServlet.getConfigNodeFromZIP(RegisterPackageServlet.java:121)  at org.pentaho.di.www.RegisterPackageServlet.generateBody(RegisterPackageServlet.java:96)   at org.pentaho.di.www.BodyHttpServlet.doGet(BodyHttpServlet.java:71)    at org.pentaho.di.www.BaseHttpServlet.doPost(BaseHttpServlet.java:103)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52) at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:522)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043) at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:957) at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: Error reading information from input streamInvalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.    at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:635)  at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:559)  at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:540)  at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:526)  ... 30 moreCaused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 78; Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence. at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)    at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:612)  ... 33 moreCaused by: org.apache.xerces.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.    at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(Unknown Source) at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source)    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source) at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanContent(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanContent(Unknown Source)    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)    ... 37 more
2018/06/24 14:58:54 - 工单 - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2018/06/24 14:58:54 - 工单 - There was an error passing the exported transformation to the remote server: 
2018/06/24 14:58:54 - 工单 - org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: Error reading information from input streamInvalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.Error reading information from input streamInvalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.   at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:528)  at org.pentaho.di.www.RegisterPackageServlet.getConfigNodeFromZIP(RegisterPackageServlet.java:121)  at org.pentaho.di.www.RegisterPackageServlet.generateBody(RegisterPackageServlet.java:96)   at org.pentaho.di.www.BodyHttpServlet.doGet(BodyHttpServlet.java:71)    at org.pentaho.di.www.BaseHttpServlet.doPost(BaseHttpServlet.java:103)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52) at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:522)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043) at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:957) at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: Error reading information from input streamInvalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.    at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:635)  at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:559)  at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:540)  at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:526)  ... 30 moreCaused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 78; Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence. at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)    at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:612)  ... 33 moreCaused by: org.apache.xerces.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.    at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(Unknown Source) at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source)    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source) at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanContent(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanContent(Unknown Source)    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)    ... 37 more
2018/06/24 14:58:54 - 工单 - 
2018/06/24 14:58:54 - 工单 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans.sendToSlaveServer(Trans.java:4263)
2018/06/24 14:58:54 - 工单 -  at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.trans.JobEntryTrans.execute(JobEntryTrans.java:1037)
2018/06/24 14:58:54 - 工单 -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:676)
2018/06/24 14:58:54 - 工单 -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:817)
2018/06/24 14:58:54 - 工单 -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:493)
2018/06/24 14:58:54 - 工单 -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.run(Job.java:380)
```

appreciate if can help me solve the problem!!

**-- problem update：**

I created a slave server to run my job：
[job configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENmmY.png)

There is slave server locale information：[slave server local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3LqJ.png)

There is my job information:[job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCIcT.png)

Job Code：[job code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djadp.png)

Transformation Code：[transformation code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P3lq.jpg)

when I run my job by remote, I encountered the exception as below:

```
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
There was an error passing the exported job to the remote server: 
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: 
Error reading information from input streamInvalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
Error reading information from input streamInvalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.

 at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:528)
 at org.pentaho.di.www.RegisterPackageServlet.getConfigNodeFromZIP(RegisterPackageServlet.java:121)
 at org.pentaho.di.www.RegisterPackageServlet.generateBody(RegisterPackageServlet.java:86)
 at org.pentaho.di.www.BodyHttpServlet.doGet(BodyHttpServlet.java:71)
 at org.pentaho.di.www.BaseHttpServlet.doPost(BaseHttpServlet.java:103)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:522)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:957)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

 Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: Error reading information from input streamInvalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
 at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:635)
 at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:559)
 at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:540)
 at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:526) ... 30 more

 Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 78; Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
 at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
 at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
 at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:612) ... 33 more

 Caused by: org.apache.xerces.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanContent(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanContent(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)   ... 37 more

    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.sendToSlaveServer(Job.java:1674)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonJobDelegate.executeJob(SpoonJobDelegate.java:1402)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.executeJob(Spoon.java:8698)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.executeFile(Spoon.java:8657)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.runFile(Spoon.java:8622)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.job.JobGraph.runJob(JobGraph.java:3410)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.job.JobGraph$11.widgetSelected(JobGraph.java:1437)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1375)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:8104)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9466)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:701)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
```

The following block is the log I found:

```
2018/06/25 18:22:30 - Spoon - Spoon
2018/06/25 18:22:43 - Spoon - Spoon
2018/06/25 18:22:48 - Spoon - Spoon
2018/06/25 18:23:14 -  - Loading transformation from XML file [file:///D:/资料/项目相关/茅台项目/ktr/check_order_migration.ktr]
2018/06/25 18:23:25 -  - Loading transformation from XML file [file:///D:/资料/项目相关/茅台项目/ktr/check_order_migration.ktr]
2018/06/25 18:23:31 -  - Loading transformation from XML file [file:///D:/资料/项目相关/茅台项目/ktr/check_order_migration.ktr]
2018/06/25 18:23:40 -  - Loading transformation from XML file [file:///D:/资料/项目相关/茅台项目/ktr/check_order_migration.ktr]
2018/06/25 18:23:40 - maotai-dev - 连接到: [http://118.31.135.238:8888/kettle/registerPackage/?type=job&load=myJob.kjb]
2018/06/25 18:23:40 - maotai-dev - 响应状态码: [200]
2018/06/25 18:23:40 - maotai-dev - "响应主体: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><webresult>  <result>ERROR</result>  <message>org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: Error reading information from input streamInvalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.Error reading information from input streamInvalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.    at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:528)  at org.pentaho.di.www.RegisterPackageServlet.getConfigNodeFromZIP(RegisterPackageServlet.java:121)  at org.pentaho.di.www.RegisterPackageServlet.generateBody(RegisterPackageServlet.java:86)   at org.pentaho.di.www.BodyHttpServlet.doGet(BodyHttpServlet.java:71)    at org.pentaho.di.www.BaseHttpServlet.doPost(BaseHttpServlet.java:103)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52) at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:522)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043) at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:957) at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: Error reading information from input streamInvalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.    at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:635)  at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:559)  at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:540)  at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:526)  ... 30 moreCaused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 78; Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence. at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)    at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:612)  ... 33 moreCaused by: org.apache.xerces.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.    at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(Unknown Source) at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source)    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source) at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanContent(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanContent(Unknown Source)    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)    ... 37 more</message>  <id/></webresult>
2018/06/25 18:23:40 - maotai-dev - Sent export file to service [/kettle/registerPackage] on host [118.31.135.238]
2018/06/25 18:30:08 -  - Loading transformation from XML file [file:///D:/资料/项目相关/茅台项目/ktr/check_order_migration.ktr]
2018/06/25 18:30:10 -  - Loading transformation from XML file [file:///D:/资料/项目相关/茅台项目/ktr/check_order_migration.ktr]
```

Then I checked the link as I got the response:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<webresult>
<result>ERROR</result>
<message>
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleFileException: Unable to get VFS File object for filename 'zip:file:///tmp/export_288aa432-7863-11e8-a210-712b51b61c68.zip!__job_execution_configuration__.xml' : Could not open Zip file "/tmp/export_288aa432-7863-11e8-a210-712b51b61c68.zip". Unable to get VFS File object for filename 'zip:file:///tmp/export_288aa432-7863-11e8-a210-712b51b61c68.zip!__job_execution_configuration__.xml' : Could not open Zip file "/tmp/export_288aa432-7863-11e8-a210-712b51b61c68.zip". at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:528) at org.pentaho.di.www.RegisterPackageServlet.getConfigNodeFromZIP(RegisterPackageServlet.java:121) at org.pentaho.di.www.RegisterPackageServlet.generateBody(RegisterPackageServlet.java:86) at org.pentaho.di.www.BodyHttpServlet.doGet(BodyHttpServlet.java:71) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52) at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:522) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033) at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644) at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleFileException: Unable to get VFS File object for filename 'zip:file:///tmp/export_288aa432-7863-11e8-a210-712b51b61c68.zip!__job_execution_configuration__.xml' : Could not open Zip file "/tmp/export_288aa432-7863-11e8-a210-712b51b61c68.zip". at org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.KettleVFS.getFileObject(KettleVFS.java:165) at org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.KettleVFS.getFileObject(KettleVFS.java:107) at org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.KettleVFS.getFileObject(KettleVFS.java:103) at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:526) ... 29 more
</message>
<id/>
</webresult>
```

finally,  I checked the file "/tmp/export_288aa432-7863-11e8-a210-712b51b61c68.zip" on Slave server , its length is 0 byte...

thanks!!!

Comment: Have a look at the code [here](https://github.com/cwarden/kettle/blob/master/src-core/org/pentaho/di/core/xml/XMLHandler.java). Show us a minimal example of the code and xml-file you use.

Comment: Also it would be nice if the log were limited to 80 characters.

Comment: Hi, can you please help me to have a look at my update for the problem??many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**"Error reading information from input streamInvalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence"**

it seems you are parsing in a encoding (UTF-8) wich is not the real one.
Maybe the real one is utf16? if you dont know , you will have to ask to the data creator, otherwise there is no way to know the original encoding.

This is extracted from the wikipedia page of utf 16 : *"UTF-16 arose from an earlier fixed-width 16-bit encoding known as UCS-2 (for 2-byte Universal Character Set) once it became clear that 16 bits were not sufficient for Unicode's user community".*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue on how Pentaho uploads and parse the XML thought a slave server upload.
Your step names/comments can't have any special UTF-8 characters like í, õ, â or even Chinese/Japanese characters.

Update:
You can fix this issue by including to your PDI startup script the "file.encoding=utf8" parameter.

```
[Spoon.bat]
if "%PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS%"=="" set PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx512m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" "-Dfile.encoding=utf8"

[Spoon.sh]
OPT="$OPT $PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS -Dfile.encoding=utf8 -Djava.library.path=$LIBPATH -DKETTLE_HOME=$KETTLE_HOME -DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=$KETTLE_REPOSITORY -DKETTLE_USER=$KETTLE_USER -DKETTLE_PASSWORD=$KETTLE_PASSWORD -DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=$KETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES -DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=$KETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT"
```

Remember to also update your server/carte startup scripts.